# Can GITHub commits be pushed to a new branch? Or are they already committed to the original?

Tags: git, github, push, commit

I've made some changes to my local version of the code and committed them, but I want to push them to a new branch.  I'm worried that when I push my changes, they'll all affect the master branch.

Is it a problem that I've "committed" my changes?  Or will those commits only be applied to the new branch that I create?

I'm a total GITHub no00b, so go easy with me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use an explicit push command

```
git push origin <branch-name>
```

Only this branch will push  to the github repository.

You can also revert your commit, if you affect something in the master branch.
Use

```
git reset HEAD~<commits count>
```

For dropping all changes of the commit:

```
git reset HEAD~<commits count> --hard
```

I'm recommending you the ProGit book to learn more about GIT https://github.com/progit/progit

Answer (score 0):

That depends whether the branch is a sub of the master branch. I suggest you go here for more in depth detail.

http://learn.github.com/p/branching.html

Comment: I want to create a branch which is a sub of the master branch, yes.  Thanks - I'll take a look at that link.

Comment: Alrighty. Hope it helps. I don't know much of Git myself, but this whole branching thing is good for organizing mass developers working of different parts of a complex project.